# Centering content of centering div block

Tags: html, css

We can centering content of div block like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <form> <input type="text"/> </form>
</div>
```

`css`-style:

```
.parent{
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    border: 1px solid #dd0;
    background: #ffa;    
}
```

It's ok to centering form here. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bundos/ZLLVu/). But if we add some margin to `div.parent` we lost  vertical centering form. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bundos/g4xfx/). Please explain me why it's occuring?

Comment: You also changed the position to absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a margin to your cell, try this code:

```
    .parent{
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    border: 1px solid #dd0;
    background: #ffa;    
}

input[type=text] {
    margin: 20px;   
    position: absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/markom/ZLLVu/3/

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: absolute;` and it works fine!

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4xfx/1/)

Comment: And there is margin of div.parent block.

Answer (score 0):

Remove: position: absolute;

This is because position:absolute; forces display:block; and that is not what you want.  you want it to remain display: table-cell;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center your container horizontally and vertically take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/g4xfx/3/show/

`.parent` is also centered if you resize the browser window. The content, in your case the 
`form`, is also horizontally and vertically centered within the parent container.

```
.parent {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:-250px;
    margin-left:-250px;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    border: 1px solid #dd0;
    background: #ffa;
    display:table;
}
.parent form {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```